# Keeping the UI responsive while parsing a very large logfile

Tags: c#, file-io, user-interface, treeview, backgroundworker

I'm writing an app that parses a very large logfile, so that the user can see the contents in a treeview format. I've used a BackGroundWorker to read the file, and as it parses each message, I use a BeginInvoke to get the GUI thread to add a node to my treeview. Unfortunately, there's two issues:

- The treeview is unresponsive to clicks or scrolls while the file is being parsed. I would like users to be able to examine (ie expand) nodes while the file is parsing, so that they don't have to wait for the whole file to finish parsing.
- The treeview flickers each time a new node is added.

Here's the code inside the form:

```
private void btnChangeDir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog browser = new OpenFileDialog();

    if (browser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        tbSearchDir.Text = browser.FileName;
        BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw.DoWork += (ob, evArgs) => ParseFile(tbSearchDir.Text);
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}

private void ParseFile(string inputfile)
{
    FileStream logFileStream = new FileStream(inputfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    StreamReader LogsFile = new StreamReader(logFileStream);

    while (!LogsFile.EndOfStream)
    {
        string Msgtxt = LogsFile.ReadLine();
        Message msg = new Message(Msgtxt.Substring(26)); //Reads the text into a class with appropriate members
        AddTreeViewNode(msg);
    }
}

private void AddTreeViewNode(Message msg)
{
    TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(msg.SeqNum);

    BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                               {
                                   treeView1.BeginUpdate();
                                   treeView1.Nodes.Add(newNode);
                                   treeView1.EndUpdate();
                                   Refresh();
                               }
                    )); 
}
```

What needs to be changed?

**EDIT**

```
New code, to replace the last function above:
        List<TreeNode> nodeQueue = new List<TreeNode>(1000);

        private void AddTreeViewNode(Message msg)
        {
            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(msg.SeqNum);

            nodeQueue.Add(newNode);

            if (nodeQueue.Count == 1000)
            {
                var buffer = nodeQueue.ToArray();
                nodeQueue.Clear();
                BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                                           {
                                               treeView1.BeginUpdate();
                                               treeView1.Nodes.AddRange(buffer);
                                               treeView1.EndUpdate();
                                               Refresh();
                                               Application.DoEvents();
                                           }
                                ));
            }
        }
```

Not sure why I left the Refresh and the DoEvents in there. A bit of testing other comments...

Comment: How quickly are new nodes being added?  Are the nodes you are pulling from the textfile very smaller and just large in quantity, or are the nodes them selves larger?  If you are updating the TreeView rapidly then you are going to have a hard time keeping it responsive.  One solution might be to batch the updates.  For example if you have millions of TreeView nodes have your code store 100 or so nodes in a list and then update them all as one action, instead of updating each one individually.

Comment: There's going to be loads and loads of nodes, but each node has only a few children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Invoke/BeginInvoke` uses `PostMessage` internally to marshal a request from an arbitrary thread to the UI thread. `BeginInvoke` will be flooding your windows message queue with messages which need to be processed by the UI thread, that accompanied by the fact that you are disabling the tree redraw with every node you add is probably impacting your ability to interact with the tree while it is loading.

One option would be to batch a number of updates together and then send them update the tree in batches. So parse the file and update the tree with every 100 or some number of nodes rather than 1 at a time.

Update: After your edit to add nodes in batches I would suggest the following.

1- Rather use `Invoke` than `BeginInvoke`, otherwise the queue fills up while the tree is being updated and then once the tree is updated the next thousand nodes are ready to be inserted which puts you right back where you where.

2- Sleep a few 100 milliseconds after inserting each batch so that there is a period that UI can respond. You can play with this, this will balance performance vs. user experience. Longer sleep will feel more responsive for the user, but will ultimately take longer to get all the data loaded.

3- Note that your current batching solution will miss the last few nodes if the total count is not a multiple of 1000

```
    private void AddTreeViewNode(Message msg) 
    { 
        TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(msg.SeqNum); 

        nodeQueue.Add(newNode); 

        if (nodeQueue.Count == 1000) 
        { 
            var buffer = nodeQueue.ToArray(); 
            nodeQueue.Clear(); 
            Invoke(new Action(() => 
                { 
                    treeView1.BeginUpdate(); 
                    treeView1.Nodes.AddRange(buffer); 
                    treeView1.EndUpdate(); 
                }));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: The batch method is something I do with a log file viewer I made as well.  I'm not doing it in ANY way similar to the OP, but if you don't batch them you will have near-infinite flicker.

Comment: Ok, I've implemented a batching scheme. That removes the flicker. But I'm still unable to interact with the control while it is having nodes added to it further down the treeview...

Comment: @Carlos, at the moment items are being added you will not be able to interact with the control because of the BeginUpdate/EndUpdate which prevents updates occuring. You should post a  sample of the updated code for further comment.

Comment: @Chris Taylor: Code is edited now. Form is unresponsive, can't be dragged.

Comment: @Chris Taylor: I just made some modifications, as you specified, and played around with the buffer size and sleep length. I eventually found a nice combination that reads the file at a reasonable rate while still allowing scrolling. Only one issue left, which I discovered towards the end of the file... the batches at the end seem to take longer to do than those at the beginning?

Comment: @Carlos, this is probably a progresive degradation in performance of the actual tree control due to the volume of items you are adding. Roughly how many items are you currently loading into the control?

Comment: @Christ Taylor: My test file is about 100MB, leading to around 90K entries in the tree. I'm going to put in filtering, so hopefully when it comes to actually using the program, there will be significantly fewer entries.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you'll want to do is enable double-buffering on the TreeView so it will stop flickering.  That's supported since Vista but unfortunately not by Windows Forms.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the control from the top of the toolbox onto your form.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class BufferedTreeView : TreeView {
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        IntPtr style = (IntPtr)TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER;
        SendMessage(this.Handle, TVM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE, (IntPtr)style, (IntPtr)style);
    }
    // P/Invoke:
    private const int TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER = 0x004;
    private const int TVM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE = 0x1100 + 44;
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
}
```

Keeping your UI responsive requires a redesign of your ParseFile() method.  As written, it calls BeginInvoke() much too frequently.  That floods the UI thread with requests it cannot keep up with.  It doesn't get around its normal duties anymore, like painting and responding to mouse clicks.

It is wasted effort, the human eye cannot perceive updates that happen at a rate faster than 25 times per second.  Store the data in a collection, BeginInvoke and pass that collection at a much slower rate.

Answer (score 0):

did you tryed `Application.Doevents()` method?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't run your code with profiler but if you consider slow I/O as botleneck you may try
[MemoryMappedFile from .NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx).

So instead of seeking and reading line by line from disk you will have an access to the same data in memory instead of disk IO.